# xstream fromXML timestamp issue

Tags: java, xml, xstream

am using the following code to read my xml using xstream

```
    XStream xStream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
 xStream.processAnnotations(Class.forName(requestType));
 Object reqInfo = null;
 reqInfo = xStream.fromXML(testCaseData.getRequest());
```

The code is working for other xmls . When i give timestamp as input , i am getting following error :

```
Cannot construct javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar : null : Cannot construct javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar : null 

message             : Cannot construct javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar : null
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ObjectAccessException
cause-message       : Cannot construct javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar : null
```

I tried giving multiple timestamp formats, But still am getting the same error. please help.

```
<GeXXXRequest>            
            <client>
               <clientId>111</clientId>
               <appservername>111</appservername>
               <apptimestamp>2004-02-22 15:16:04.0 UTC</apptimestamp>
            </client>
</GeXXXRequest>
```

Answer (score 0):

In XML, your timestamp should conform to the [ISO 8601](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#isoformats) format, see link.

In your case, '2004-02-22T15:16:04.0+00:00' should work.

Comment: I tried 2004-02-22T15:16:04.0+00:00 . Still am getting the same error.

Comment: Nope. Even "2004-02-22T15:16:04Z" doesnt Work .